# Schur Weyl Duality

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I'm studiyng the Schur Weyl duality in this PDF (http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/Finite%20Group%20Rep%20Theory7.pdf) and i'm trying to understand the following theorem

> Theorem: The subalgebra of $End(V^{\otimes n})$ spanned by the image of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is $B = End_{\mathbb{C}[S_{n}]}(V^{\otimes n})$

In the proof the author states:
$$B = End_{\mathbb{C}[S_{n}]}(V^{\otimes n})$$
$$= End(V^{\otimes n})^{S_{n}}$$
$$\cong(End(V^{\otimes n}))^{S_{n}}$$
$$\cong Sym^{n}End(V)$$

I would like to know the definition of $End(V^{\otimes n})^{S_{n}}$. Also, I would like to understand how to prove this sequence of isomorphisms.

Thank you in advance

Comment: In this situation, $End(V^{\otimes n})^{S_n}$ is the set of $S_n$-fixed points in $End(V^{\otimes n})$ with the action of $S_n$ on $End(V^{\otimes n})$ being induced by the action on $V^{\otimes n}$. So for $\sigma \in S_n$ and $f \in End(V^{\otimes n})$ we have  
$$ (\sigma \cdot f)(x) = \sigma f(\sigma^{-1}x).$$
A fixed point under this action is then nothing else then a morphism of $\mathbb{C} [S_n]$-endomorphism of $V^{\otimes n}$ which explains the first equality. Note that the third line should read $(End(V)^{\otimes n})^{S_n}$, otherwise it would be the same as the second.